# Selenium Java after buton click i do not get expected results

Tags: java, selenium, automation, onclick, click

This is my method for bypass google verification

```
public void notABot( ) {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds( 25 ) );
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-') and starts-with (@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div [ @class =  'recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and that is working. In test I also put sleep to slow down selenium little bit.

After that i need to click on the button to confirm registration.
There is info about button.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button bc-blue register-button-link submit-button sign-up" data-tracking-category="Üyelik" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-label="ÜyeOl" tabindex="27">Otvorite nalog</a>
```

But i do not get expected result

I try to find button @Findby xpath by class and href. Test click on the button and test pass but i do not get what I need.

This is what is happening when test pass:
[image]

and I need to get this

[image]

I try simple click, java script executor, and I am stacked. I do not know how to solve this.
I hope someone could help me

Comment: Post the URL to have a look.

Comment: https://www.lcwaikiki.rs/sr-RS/RS/register

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code, it's working fine for me, while clicking on the captcha check box, we have to solve it manually.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("RegisterFormView_RegisterEmail")).sendKeys("email");
driver.findElement(By.id("RegisterFormView_Password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("RegisterPhoneNumberTR")).sendKeys("99536871");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@class='iCheck-helper'])[3]")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(".//*[@title='reCAPTCHA']")));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".recaptcha-checkbox-border")).click();

Thread.sleep(15000);  // in this time you have to solve the captcha manually

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button.bc-blue.register-button-link")).click();
```

Comment: I emphasized that the part with I'm not a robot is working. After solving I'm not a robot next button doesn't work.

Comment: I couldn't able to check that, because it is sending a code to the entered mobile number. I am not from that country,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void notABot( ) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds( 15 ));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-') and starts-with (@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div [ @class =  'recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click( );
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

After this I use

```
@FindBy ( xpath = "//a[@class='button bc-blue register-button-link submit-button sign-up']")
WebElement openAccount;
```

and

```
public void confirmRegistrationButton( ) {

    openAccount.click();
}
```

but i still do not get second picture but test fails with explanation

```
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (2a833ab11bb1c901d95f62bde96b50a9)] -> xpath: //span/following-sibling::input[@id='RegisterFormView_ActivationCode']]
```

and this is normal because i did not get that box on picture two

her is link to Git so maybe someone can help[Button Otvorite nalog](https://github.com/mvujaklija/PracticingOfAutomaticTesting-/tree/main/JAVA-development/src)